# select total bill amount at monthwise

Tags: sql-server

I am already asked in previous question. How to get the sum of total bill amounts. No I am want to the bill amount calculated at range of dates. In my end user select 01/07/2017 to 10/07/2017  or 01/07/2017 to 15/07/0217 or 01/07/2017 to 31/07/217 such as these different formats. How I populate the total amount of the bill amount at my user.

this code is I used to select the total sum of the bills.

```
 select a.Name , sum(s.NetAmount) NetAmount   from Sales as s, AccountHead as a where s.ConsumerID=a.id and a.name='tamizh' group by a.Name
```

My user "tamizh" select her bills at  01/07/2017 to 15/07/2017. How to I populate the total amount at between these dates.

How to I Re-write my last code to get this output.

Comment: What is your sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add the date filter in your query as below:

```
 select a.Name , sum(s.NetAmount) NetAmount   from Sales as s, AccountHead as a where s.ConsumerID=a.id and a.name='tamizh'
```

AND (DATE_COLUMN >='01/07/2017' AND DATE_COLUMN<=15/07/2017)
 group by a.Name

.You can use parameters for date i.e. date1 & date2. Like i below:

```
select a.Name , sum(s.NetAmount) NetAmount   from Sales as s, AccountHead as a where s.ConsumerID=a.id and a.name='tamizh'
```

AND (DATE_COLUMN >=@FromDate AND DATE_COLUMN<=@ToDate)
 group by a.Name

Let me know the progress.
Regards,

Comment: this method displayed a empty values. just display the column header (name, total amount) but doesn't return values which selected the corresponding user.

Comment: hey , its worked. I  forgot it to put the date with in  single quotes. sorry for the previous comment. Thanks  buddy :)

Comment: plz check that data is present in your database table between the two dates for this particular user.

Comment: ok Vinayak, i am happy that it worked for you, plz mark my reply as answer. thanks

Comment: will u please say how to I display in no of days at new column.  like username  billamnt no.of days  when I select 01/07/17 - 10/07/17 the result will be displayed at user1 10000  10 as belown at mentioned columns.

Comment: Vinayak, please explain your question in a bit more detail. If you mean that you want to get the column NUMBER_OF_DAYS in your query, then you should simply add this in your Select query : a.NUMBER_OF_DAYS. Like: Select a.Name , sum(s.NetAmount) NetAmount,a.NUMBER_OF_DAYs from ....... WHERE ..... if this is not your question, then plz explain it more. thanks

Comment: yes. I want to get the  column no. of days in my query. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So, my suggestion helped you to accomplish what you want? Or you still need some more help?

Comment: hi buddy, I post my doubt in my another question.

Answer (score 0):

try to filter the origin data in this way before GROUP BY

```
select d.Name , sum(d.NetAmount) NetAmount   from 
(SELECT * FROM Sales as s, AccountHead as a where s.ConsumerID=a.id and a.name='tamizh'AND s.[Date] BETWEEN '2017/07/01' AND '2017/07/15') as d
group by d.Name
```